# CSS horizontal menu problems in Firefox and Windows

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I'm working on a horizontal menu with a logo in the middle on a project. I've been using Chrome and Safari mostly during the coding to view it. Today though I switched over to Firefox to check things out and my menu went crazy. Then I checked IE and Chrome on a PC and it was the same problem.

Here are screenshots. Currently it's local on my machine or I'd give a URL.

**Chrome 35 OS X**
[image: Chrome 35 OS X]

**Firefox 30 OS X**
[image: Firefox 30 OS X]

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="header-nav-container">

    <ul class="initial-nav left">
        <li><a class="active" href="#">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">talk</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">topics</a></li>
    </ul>

<img id="header-logo" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo_full_text.svg" alt="I Am Moved logo">

    <ul class="initial-nav right">
        <li><a href="#">shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
        <li class="sys"><a href="#">share your story</a></li>
    </ul>
</div> <!-- /#header-nav-container -->
```

And my CSS (compiled from LESS):

```
body.home div#header div#header-nav-container {
  margin-top: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul.initial-nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  border-bottom: 12px solid #00ffab;
  width: 375px;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  -webkit-animation: fadeInDown 0.75s 0.15s;
  -moz-animation: fadeInDown 0.75s 0.15s;
  -o-animation: fadeInDown 0.75s 0.15s;
  animation: fadeInDown 0.75s 0.15s;
}
ul.initial-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul.initial-nav li a {
  color: inherit;
}
ul.initial-nav li a.active {
  border-bottom: 13px solid #ff5071;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
ul.initial-nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul.initial-nav li.sys {
  color: #5fd6e5;
  font-weight: 600;
}
ul.initial-nav.left {
  text-align: left;
}
ul.initial-nav.left li:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-left: 110.5px;
}
ul.initial-nav.right {
  text-align: left;
}
ul.initial-nav.right li:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-left: 51px;
}

body.home img#header-logo {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-right: 33px;
  -webkit-animation: fadeInUp 0.75s;
  -moz-animation: fadeInUp 0.75s;
  -o-animation: fadeInUp 0.75s;
  animation: fadeInUp 0.75s;
}
```

I made my margins on the `<li>`'s super precise so that the menu items would fill up the menu width perfectly. I'm not sure if there's a better way to do that. I've messed with the margins to see if the text is just overflowing but there's no change in FF, IE or Chrome on Windows.

I was originally targeting all but the first `<li>` using li + li in my CSS to add margins between the menu items but switched to the :not(:first-of-type) selector just to test. It didn't seem to make a difference. I've searched around but haven't had any luck. Especially because I have no idea what's causing it.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

After a little more experimenting, it looks like the margin WAS causing the problem. The reason it didn't make a difference when I changed it before was because I was targeting the `<li>` with the li + li selector. When I targeted it with li:not(first-of-type) and reduced the margins, everything fit on one line again and it rendered properly on Windows and in Firefox on my Mac.

Hopefully that's all it was! Fingers crossed.

Comment: The only thing that does bother me about this is that my menu items don't span the full width of the menu. If anyone has any suggestions on how to make `<li>` elements span the width of a div I'd love to hear them. I searched around and this was the best I could come up with without having to use JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

One ul.initial-nav class css just increase width . You had also give css hack for firefox and chrome also so it doesn't display same both browser .

Let me know after changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul.initial-nav li a.active {
  border-bottom: 15px solid #FF0000;
  bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/wUf7T/